# small circle area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, area

I have tried to solve this problem, but I can not see its solution.
It is to calculate the area of the small circle, which is tangent to the left arc to the right and to the Y axis in points that I do not know.
If I knew these points I could easily reach the solution, some idea of how to approach it

attached image of the problem[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $(a,b)$ the center of the circle and $r$ the radius of the larger circles. Notice that $a$ is also the radius of the circle in question.  We have
$$r-\text{distance from $(a,b)$ to $(0,r)$}=a$$
and
$$\text{distance from $(a,b)$ to $(r,0)$}-r=a,$$
that is
$$r-\sqrt{a^2+(b-r)^2}=a\quad\text{and}\quad
\sqrt{(a-r)^2+b^2}-r=a.$$
From here we easily deduce $b=\frac43r$ and $a=\frac49r$.

Comment: +1. What an elegant solution! It is a general solution for large circles of any radius (not only $9$ as it may look like on the graph).

Comment: @farruhota Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the point of tangency is on the line between the centers.  Let the point of tangency be $(x,y)$ and the radius of the small circle be $r$ with the center of the small circle at $(r,z)$.  You have that $(x,y)$ is on both circles, that the slopes from the centers to $(x,y)$ are equal and that the segment is divided in the ratio of the radii.  This gives four equations in four unknowns.
$$(9-x)^2+y^2=81\\(x-r)^2+(z-y)^2=r^2\\\frac {x-r}{9-r}=\frac r{9+r}\\\frac{z-y}z=\frac r{9+r}$$
 [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(9-x)%5E2%2By%5E2%3D81,(x-r)%5E2%2B(z-y)%5E2%3Dr%5E2,(x-r)%2F(9-r)%3Dr%2F(9%2Br),(z-y)%2Fz%3Dr%2F(9%2Br)) seems to say I am still an equation short.

The missing equation reflects the tangency of the small circle with the large circle on the left.  As the line from $(0,9)$ through $(r,z)$ hits the point of tangency we have $$r^2+(z-9)^2=(9-r)^2$$
Now [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(9-x)%5E2%2By%5E2%3D81,(x-r)%5E2%2B(z-y)%5E2%3Dr%5E2,(x-r)%2F(9-r)%3Dr%2F(9%2Br),(z-y)%2Fz%3Dr%2F(9%2Br),r%5E2%2B(9-z)%5E2%3D(9-r)%5E2) finds 
$$r=4, x=\frac {72,13},y=\frac {108}{13},z=12$$

Comment: @ Ross Millikan Thank you ,using wolfram alpha gives me approximately  x =12., y = -8.48528, z = 8.48528, r = 18   and   x =12, y = 8.48528, z = -8.48528, r =18 , **Should they all be positive?**

Comment: Yes, they should all be positive and clearly $r$ is about $4$ if we believe the figure.

Comment: I had done the similar triangles wrong.  I have updated the last two equations, which are based on dropping a vertical from $(r,z)$ to the $x$ axis. [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(9-x)%5E2%2By%5E2%3D81,(x-r)%5E2%2B(z-y)%5E2%3Dr%5E2,(x-r)%2F(9-r)%3Dr%2F(9%2Br),(z-y)%2Fz%3Dr%2F(9%2Br)) now seems to say I am still an equation short.

Comment: I think the small circle must be fixed to the second large circle too, otherwise the two points (center of small circle and tangent of small and large circles) can freely move and all the above conditions can still hold.

Answer (score 0):

Label as indicated on the graph:

$\hspace{1.5cm}$$[image]

The equations:
$$\begin{align}(x-r)^2+(y-s)^2&=r^2 \ \ (\text{small circle})\\
(a-r)^2+(b-s)^2&=r^2 \ \ (\text{small circle})\\
(x-9)^2+(y-0)^2&=9^2 \ \ (\text{horizontal semicircle})\\
(a-9)^2+(b-0)^2&=9^2 \ \ (\text{vertical semicircle})\\
s^2+(9-r)^2&=(9+r)^2 \ \ (\text{large triangle})\\
(s-9)^2&=(9-2r)\cdot 9 \ \ (\text{green line})\\
\end{align}$$
We will (set up and make [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%5E2%2B(9-r)%5E2%3D(9%2Br)%5E2;%20(x-r)%5E2%2B(y-s)%5E2%3Dr%5E2;%20(x-9)%5E2%2By%5E2%3D9%5E2;%20(a-r)%5E2%2B(b-s)%5E2%3Dr%5E2;%20a%5E2%2B(b-9)%5E2%3D9%5E2;%20(s-9)%5E2%3D(9-2r)*9;%20x%3E0,y%3E0,s%3E0,r%3E0,%20a%3E0,b%3E0)) solve the $6$ equations with $6$ unknowns and get:
$$a=\frac{36}{5}; b=\frac{72}{5}; r=4; s=12; x=\frac{72}{13}; y=\frac{108}{13}.$$
Hence, the area is: $A=\pi\cdot r^2=16\pi \approx 50.265$.

Comment: thank you all for your answers, it has been understood very well